# Cannot start mysql or mysqld_safe on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, mysql

My Ubuntu runs in docker and I need to use Percona, however, the mysqld cannot be started. I have been trying to fix this for 2 days. I don't think it's a permission issue, but I am not sure if any of my configuration is incorrect. The following is my Ubuntu version, and it runs inside docker.

`3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

#### my.cnf

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1

log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

This is the initial error log when mysql tries to init itself.

#### /var/log/error.log

```
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 'none'
2014-10-17 15:43:27 7fe0e0f2e780 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-10-17 15:43:27 7fe0e0f2e780 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases. Please use READ COMMITTED transaction isolation level instead, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html.
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 12 MB
2014-10-17 15:43:27 53 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
2014-10-17 15:43:28 53 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile101 size to 128 MB
InnoDB: Progress in MB: 100
2014-10-17 15:43:34 53 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 128 MB
InnoDB: Progress in MB: 100
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file ./ib_logfile101 to ./ib_logfile0
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.20-68.0 started; log sequence number 0
2014-10-17 15:43:43 7fe0c246e700 InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from .//ib_buffer_pool
2014-10-17 15:43:43 7fe0c246e700 InnoDB: Cannot open './/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Warning] Bootstrap mode disables GTIDs. Bootstrap mode should only be used by mysql_install_db which initializes the MySQL data directory and creates system tables.
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2014-10-17 15:43:43 53 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2014-10-17 15:43:44 53 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
2014-10-17 15:43:45 53 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
2014-10-17 15:43:45 53 [Note] Binlog end
2014-10-17 15:43:45 53 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-10-17 15:43:45 53 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-10-17 15:43:45 7fe0c246e700 InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to .//ib_buffer_pool
2014-10-17 15:43:45 7fe0c246e700 InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 141017 15:43:45
2014-10-17 15:43:47 53 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625977
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 'none'
2014-10-17 15:43:47 7fc35fa5c780 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-10-17 15:43:47 7fc35fa5c780 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases. Please use READ COMMITTED transaction isolation level instead, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html.
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.20-68.0 started; log sequence number 1625977
2014-10-17 15:43:47 7fc340fd0700 InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from .//ib_buffer_pool
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Warning] Bootstrap mode disables GTIDs. Bootstrap mode should only be used by mysql_install_db which initializes the MySQL data directory and creates system tables.
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2014-10-17 15:43:47 7fc340fd0700 InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 141017 15:43:47
2014-10-17 15:43:47 221 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
2014-10-17 15:43:48 221 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
2014-10-17 15:43:48 221 [Note] Binlog end
2014-10-17 15:43:48 221 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-10-17 15:43:48 221 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-10-17 15:43:48 7fc340fd0700 InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to .//ib_buffer_pool
2014-10-17 15:43:48 7fc340fd0700 InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 141017 15:43:48
2014-10-17 15:43:50 221 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625987
```

#### directory permission

#### /var/log/mysql

```
[16:35][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/log/mysql ]$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Oct 17 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root  4096 Oct 16 19:26 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 6927 Oct 17 15:43 error.log
[16:35][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/log/mysql ]$ cd ..
[16:35][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/log ]$ ls -al
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root      4096 Oct 16 19:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 41 root     root      4096 Oct 17 16:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql    mysql     4096 Oct 17 16:35 mysql
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Oct 16 19:26 nginx
-rw-------  1 root     root      5499 Oct 17 15:43 php5-fpm.log
-rw-------  1 root     root         0 Oct 16 19:26 php-fpm-slow.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 cwhsu    developer 4096 Oct 17 15:43 supervisor
```

#### /var/run/mysqld/

```
[16:41][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/run ]$ ls  /var/run/mysqld/ -ld
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql root 4096 Oct 16 20:15 /var/run/mysqld/
[16:42][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/run ]$ ls  /var/run/mysqld/* -ld
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5 Oct 16 20:15 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Oct 16 20:15 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.soc
```

This is the initial condition. Then I try to do `service mysql start`.

```
[16:35][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/log ]$ service mysql start
 * Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) database server mysqld
 * Please take a look at the syslog.
                                                                          [fail]
```

So I try to user `mysqld_safe` to find out what is going wrong.

```
[16:38][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/log ]$ mysqld_safe 
141017 16:40:56 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permission denied
/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid’: Permission denied
141017 16:40:56 mysqld_safe Fatal error: Can't remove the pid file:
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
Please remove it manually and start /usr/bin/mysqld_safe again;
mysqld daemon not started
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 137: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
[16:40][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/log ]$
```

Now, I have already tried this many times, so I just `sudo chmod 777 /var/run/mysql/mysql.pid` to simplify the process.

```
[16:44][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/run ]$ sudo chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
[16:46][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/run ]$ mysqld_safe 
141017 16:46:28 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid’: Permission denied
141017 16:46:28 mysqld_safe Fatal error: Can't remove the pid file:
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
Please remove it manually and start /usr/bin/mysqld_safe again;
mysqld daemon not started
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 137: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
```

If I delete the mysqld.pid and try again.

```
[16:47][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/run ]$ sudo rm -rf /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
[16:48][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/run ]$ mysqld_safe 
141017 16:49:02 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
141017 16:49:02 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock’: Permission denied
141017 16:49:02 mysqld_safe Skipping wsrep-recover for empty datadir: /var/lib/mysql
141017 16:49:02 mysqld_safe Assigning 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 to 
wsrep_start_position
141017 16:49:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Now I stuck right here and don't know what to do. Does anyone have an issue about what's going wrong?

---

### EDIT

I try the solution here https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73952.
I modify the my.cnf and add

```
#innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=ON
```

then run my start script

```
#!/bin/sh

test -x /usr/bin/mysql_install_db && test ! -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql && /usr/bin/mysql_install_db
mkdir -p /var/log/mysql && chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql && chmod 755 /var/log/mysql
mkdir -p /var/log/nginx && chown www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx && chmod 755 /var/log/nginx
```

modify my.cnf to

```
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=ON
```

run the script again and no luck...

The mysql daemon still cannot be started and if I try mysqld_safe it shows

```
[17:35][cwhsu@cwhsu:/var/lib/mysql ]$ mysqld_safe 
141017 17:35:34 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
141017 17:35:34 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 137: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock’: Permission denied
141017 17:35:34 mysqld_safe Skipping wsrep-recover for empty datadir: /var/lib/mysql
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 137: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
141017 17:35:34 mysqld_safe Assigning 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 to wsrep_start_position
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 137: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 1: eval: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
141017 17:35:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 137: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
```

Comment: this could be [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73952)... Can you try the steps 4 and 5 from the 'how to repeat' part?

Comment: no luck... Not sure if I am doing this correctly. Please see the edit part of my result.

Comment: Could you try with the `mysql`, not the `mysqld_safe`, because it seems like the `mysqld_safe` has some permission issues that the normal `mysql` doesn't have...

Comment: Oh, no sorry, I misread... I didn't see you ran it with `mysql` too... And is the error still `2014-10-17 15:43:43 7fe0c246e700 InnoDB: Cannot open './/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory`? Even with the proposed workaround?

Comment: And did you shut down mysql before running you startup script again? Because you have to shut mysql down, then change configuration, then start it again for the workaround to be effective...

Comment: I try the workaround and the `InnoDB: Cannot open './/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory` becomes `2014-10-17 17:34:06 7fb0e9d8c700 InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to .//ib_buffer_pool
2014-10-17 17:34:06 7fb0e9d8c700 InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 141017 17:34:06
2014-10-17 17:34:08 18193 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625987` However, there is a very big difference between the workaround and my condition. That is my mysqld never start successfully. I think this is something different...

Comment: Yes, so this means InnoDB dumped the buffer pool successfully, and you should be able to start MySQL normally next time without having the error `Cannot open './/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory`...

Comment: Hmm, as you say, you might have other errors related to Percona, that I don't understand... I see some errors with `WSREP` that I don't know about...

Comment: I cannot solve this issue, and we end up giving up percona xtrabackup. I actually delete everything under `/var/lib/mysql` which is my data-dir in `my.cnf`. Then I just use the data from `mysqldump` to retrieve my previous data. At least, this is how it works now. Anyway, thanks for the reply.